# Cat in script in docker

Tags: node.js, bash, docker, shell, docker-compose

I have a container with node:18-alpine3.14 as base image.
I have docker-compose file with

```
command: ["prepare_config.sh","--","npm", "run", "start-p"]
```

in prepare config

```
#!/bin/bash
json_data=$(cat <<EOF
{
    "url": "$URL"
}
EOF
)
echo "$json_data";
```

When I try to run this code I get error

```
prepare_config.sh:2
json_data=$(cat <<EOF
                  ^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1069:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:827:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47

Node.js v18.1.0
```

Could you help fix that?

Comment: It appears your script is not run by `/bin/bash`, but by node (the "entrypoint" of your image). To address your use case, you can "reset the entrypoint", and given you use `docker-compose`, you should just try to add `entrypoint: []` in your `docker-compose.yml` service definition.

Comment: please feel free to add a bit more details in your question as I suggested [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72277602/cat-in-script-in-docker/72280035?noredirect=1#comment127699116_72277939) (add more details on your Dockerfile; at least the optional `WORKDIR` and the `COPY` commands…)

Answer (score 2):

#### A quick fix (docker-compose.yml related)

It appears your script is not run by `/bin/bash`, but by node (the "[entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint)" of your image).

To address your use case, you actually have two equivalent solutions:

1. "reset the entrypoint" and directly use your `command` from the question
   → adding in your `docker-compose.yml` service definition:

```yaml
myservice:
  entrypoint: []
  command: ["prepare_config.sh", "--", "npm", "run", "start-p"]
```

2. set a nonempty `entrypoint` and `command`:
   → adding in your `docker-compose.yml` service definition, for instance:

```yaml
myservice:
  entrypoint: ["prepare_config.sh", "--"]
  command: ["npm", "run", "start-p"]
```

#### Minor remark

As an aside:

- solution 1. admits an equivalent `docker run` command:
  `docker run --entrypoint="" image-name prepare_config.sh -- npm run start-p`
- but solution 2. does not have an equivalent `docker run` command, given the CLI option `--entrypoint` can only take one argument (the program binary), not a list…

#### A better fix (Dockerfile related)

However, even if your image is based on `node:18-alpine3.14` which comes with a specific `ENTRYPOINT` that you want to override, it sounds better to directly modify your own `Dockerfile`.

Typically, you would write at the end of this file:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["prepare_config.sh", "--"]
CMD ["npm", "run", "start-p"]
```

Provided you already inserted a command to set the executable bit of your entrypoint, for instance:

```
RUN chmod a+x prepare_config.sh
```

For more details on `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`, see e.g. this other StackOverflow answer:
[What is the difference between CMD and ENTRYPOINT in a Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39408777/9164010).

Comment: I try to add `ENTRYPOINT ["./prepare_config.sh","--"]` and get very interesting error
`standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: no such file or directory`
if I remove this string I won't get this mistake.
all my files have LF (I use Ubuntu)

this code has the same result 
`entrypoint: ["prepare_config.sh", "--"] command: ["npm", "run", "start-p"]`

Comment: @klynxe Very good point. If `prepare_config.sh` is not in your PATH, one should use `./prepare_config.sh` or so. I propose to update my answer accordingly, but could you first edit your question to add more details on your Dockerfile? (at least the optional `WORKDIR` and the `COPY` commands…)

Answer (score 0):

The [entrypoint script in the node container](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/38ae136a31e276da1dc6ff6a129a4e429304582d/18/alpine3.14/docker-entrypoint.sh) tries to figure out if the command passed to it should be run by node or not.

It does that by checking if the first parameter is a system command or not. Your script is not a system command, so the entrypoint script decides that it should be run by node.

To convince the entrypoint script that your command shouldn't be run by node, you can explicitly say that you want it to be run by the shell like this

```
command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "prepare_config.sh -- npm run start-p"]
```

/bin/sh is a system command, so the entrypoint script won't try to get node to run the command.

Also, be aware that Alpine images usually don't have `bash` installed, so you might have to change `bash` in `#!/bin/bash` in your script to `sh` or `ash`.

Comment: This code start only script, but I can't see logs from npm
`command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "prepare_config.sh -- npm run start-p"]`

Comment: Your command should probably be `prepare_config.sh && npm run start-p` if you want the script to run and then the npm command afterwards.

Comment: Unless @klynxe adds `exec "$@"` or so at the end of the entrypoint script (after removing the `--` of course), because it's *always* better to try to avoid spinning an extraneous shell (`/bin/sh -c …`).

Comment: @ErikMD Yeah, but the image is the official `node` image, so that would require that they make their own, custom image.

Comment: @HansKilian are you sure? I don't think the OP uses the official `node` image but already an image *based* on `node` (given the question mentions the `prepare_config.sh` script that is certainly part of the child image(?))

Comment: You're right. I read the first line as if it was the official image. Based on the issue, I'd guess that it's still using the entrypoint from the official image though.

Answer (score 0):

Right now only this variant works fine

```
command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "./prepare_config.sh && npm run start-p"]
```